ePassport Active Authentication (ECDSA with SHA224) cannot extract public key
I'm attempting to perform Active Authentication on a passport but am struggling to extract the EC Public Key and verify the signed data. I'm using Python with the Cryptodome library. I came across a similar issue with the cryptography library, where:

These certificates don't use named curve EC parameters but instead use explicit parameters to define the curve.

However, I would would prefer to extract the public key manually rather than patching the library.
How can I extract the EC public key and verify the signature (preferably using Cryptodome)?
Signature
Sending \x01\x02\x03\0x4\0x05\x06\x07\0x8 using ISO7816 Internal Authentication command, the passport sends me the following signed data:
VW+qiTGEFEOednVlZtJ8zcTOHcZ+prkYr6D8SjVEf10ln8Zr3rffjA0ttDcX2edR7g17y4t5TA4=

Public Key
Here is the DG15:
MIIBEzCB1AYHKoZIzj0CATCByAIBATAoBgcqhkjOPQEBAh0A18E0qiZDZoYqGDAlddHXh7CfB1eX
2on1fsjA/zA8BBxopeYsqc5sHCmYA6bBUwtRThgq2LAEKlnK0p9DBBwlgPY8z+RBOIcHE7GpI2nj
PiE10mbbs3I4bEALBDkEDZAprSx+XPQ0CCOyqH3GjJ5M4xdMHm797hLAfViqVvdywHJvJMa4nk7N
rCQ1S56ZyqP203YUAs0CHQDXwTSqJkNmhioYMCV10PuY0Ra8S23evKOlp5OfAgEBAzoABF+g1Q47
ZhY88WPqtWz/HXoZx/9ydLU3S0rE0oyzwUgDklBGSbSccQqZXT6ka9OfK//DLkiXbJ1o

ASN.1
SubjectPublicKeyInfo SEQUENCE (2 elem)
    algorithm AlgorithmIdentifier SEQUENCE (2 elem)
        algorithm OBJECT IDENTIFIER 1.2.840.10045.2.1 ecPublicKey (ANSI X9.62 public key type)
        parameters ANY SEQUENCE (6 elem)
            INTEGER 1
            SEQUENCE (2 elem)
                OBJECT IDENTIFIER 1.2.840.10045.1.1 prime-field (ANSI X9.62 field type)
                INTEGER (224 bit) 2272162293...
            SEQUENCE (2 elem)
                OCTET STRING (28 byte) 68A5E62CA9...
                OCTET STRING (28 byte) 2580F63CCF...
            OCTET STRING (57 byte) 040D9029AD...
            INTEGER (224 bit) 227216229...
            INTEGER 1
    subjectPublicKey BIT STRING (456 bit) 0000010001...

Additional information
Here is the part in DG14 related to Active Authentication
MBcGBmeBCAEBBQIBAQYKBAB/AAcBAQQBAg==

ASN.1
ContentInfo SEQUENCE (3 elem)
    contentType ContentType OBJECT IDENTIFIER 2.23.136.1.1.5
    content [0] [?] INTEGER 1
    OBJECT IDENTIFIER 0.4.0.127.0.7.1.1.4.1.2 bsiEcdsaWithSHA224 (BSI TR-03111)

